# Insert records in another table using trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, triggers

Hi I am using SQLServer2008.

Below is my `Product` table.

```
ProductId
CategoryId
Name
Qty
```

where `ProductId` is primary key and auto generate. Below is my `Stock` Table

```
StockId
ProductId
Stock
```

here `StockId` is primary key and auto generate.
Now when any new reord is insert in `Product` table , I want to insert generated `ProductId` in `Stock` table using trigger. How can i do this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you please put the code for the trigger that you have tried in your question?

Comment: What have you tried? Why is there a `Qty` column in the Product table? Are you using this both for product details *and* inventory management? What value goes into the `Stock` column in the `Stock` table? (Also, you don't really need a trigger for this; you can use the OUTPUT clause on the original insert, if you don't allow cowboy data manipulation.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following. Assuming you want `stock` for new product to be defaulted to `0`. Otherwise modify accordingly.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig_Insert_Stock
ON [Product]
FOR INSERT
AS
Begin
    Insert into Stock (ProductId, Stock) 
    Select Distinct i.ProductId, 0 
    from Inserted i
End
```

Comment: +1 for guesswork, of course if ProductID is the primary key, you don't need `distinct`.

Comment: @AaronBertrand It gives error `Invalid column name 'ProductId'.`

Comment: @AaronBertrand Ok i got my mistake..sorry..your code is helpful for me. thanks.